# NLP libraries installation guidelines for java

Tags: java, ubuntu, stanford-nlp, opennlp, lingpipe

I am new to NLP. I need basic idea to get started with installation of it.
I have gone through LingPipe and open NLP installation section, but i did not get why to install maven and additional training sets , models etc.
Any brief explanation of installation would be helpful for me to get started with coding.
Platform - Ubuntu

Sorry if this question is too generic or simple

Comment: if you are not interested in maven build tool. Only OpenNLP library jar file and trained model files add that into a java project start coding.

Comment: thank you @Exbury , can you also tell me where to include trained models after downloading them ? Like jar files can be included project's build path.

Comment: you can add it directly into project structure or create a folder and add your all trained models and locate your path while loading file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used OpenNLP in my project. I think this instructions will help you to go through OpenNLP Library. Follow this [document](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html)

- Download OpenNLP Library and add it to your build path
- Download trained models and put it to a folder
- modelIn = new FileInputStream("path");

InputStream modelIn = null;

```
try {
  modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-pos-maxent.bin");
  POSModel model = new POSModel(modelIn);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  // Model loading failed, handle the error
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  if (modelIn != null) {
    try {
      modelIn.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```